# How to put a form inside a table?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to ask about how can I put a `form` with method `GET` in a `table` tag.

In the `table` element I have a text field. When I submit this form it should validate. My validation works fine but this form doesn't actually submit itself, so I can't get any value at the URL.

Below is the code:

```
<form method="GET" id="my_form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="company" form="my_form">
            </td>
            <button type="button" form="my_form" onclick="return submitvalidation();">ok</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return `true` after the validation completed.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with putting a form in a table.

You just need to have a submit button.

A plain button is designed to hang JS off and nothing else. It won't submit the form.

Use `type="submit"` not `type="button"`.

---

You should make sure that your button is in inside a table cell though. You either have an extra `</td>` or a midding `<td>`.

There doesn't seem to be any reason to use a table here at all though.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake I did had a submit type button. Sorry

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="return submitvalidation();" form="contactusform">

Comment: this is how my submit button looks like

Comment: this is a new post i just made.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493606/get-method-form-inside-a-table?noredirect=1#comment36026243_23493606