# Get method form inside a table

Tags: javascript, html

I have asked a question earlier on but I think I didn't ask the question correctly. 
This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<form method="GET" id="demotest" action="#">
    <table id="contactustable">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><h4>Contact Form:</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="15%">message </td>
            <td width="35%"><input type="text" name="message" id="message" form="demotest"></td>
            <td width="7%"><span id="error-message"></span></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="return testingvalidation();" form="demotest"> </td>
            <td width="25%"><span id="status">Message Status : </span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
function testingvalidation () {
    var message=document.getElementById("message").value;
    var error=0;

    if (message == "") {
        var msg="please enter name";
        document.getElementById("error-message").innerHTML=msg; 
        error++;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("error-message").innerHTML="";
    }

    if(error > 0) {
        var msg="Message Status : Error";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=msg; 
        return false;
    }
    else {
        messagesend="Message Status : Send";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=messagesend; 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thats my code, bbut the problem is when ever i run it and if it goes pass the validation successfully.. it would send the form using the get method.. however the message wont come up on the screen ("Message Status: Send"). If i change the return true at the bottom to return false the message comes up but then the form wont submit.

Im sorry for keep making new posts about this problem. Can someone please help me to fix this issue. Thank You

Comment: i dont know whats happend up the top but it had these at the top;

Comment: <form method="GET" id="demotest" action="#">


<table id="contactustable">
   
  <tr>

Comment: Edit your post instead of posting comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script [works fine](http://jsbin.com/gegurivi/1/edit).

You just can't see the message because the form immediately submits *and loads a new page*. The new page does not include the message.

Comment: so how do i stop the form from submitting so i can display that message?

Comment: Why would you want to? "There is nothing wrong with what you entered, but I'm going to stop it sending anyway" makes it pretty pointless having the form in the first place. If you want to tell them that everything is OK, then submit the form and give them in a message in the response.